# rails select_month default or params

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm creating an option to filter payments by month and year. It works and looks like this:
[image]

How can I show current selected params in `select_month` and `select_year` fields?

inbound_payments_controller.rb:

```
def index
  if params.has_key?(:select)
    start_date = (params[:select][:year]+"-" + params[:select][:month]+"-"+Date.today.day.to_s).to_datetime.beginning_of_month
    end_date = start_date.end_of_month
    @inbound_payments = InboundPayment.where("created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?",start_date, end_date)
  else
    @inbound_payments = InboundPayment.where("created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?", Time.now.beginning_of_month, Time.now.end_of_month)
  end
end
```

In inbound_payments/index.haml, I have a select_month helper:

```
- if params.has_key?(:select)
  = params[:select][:month]
  = params[:select][:year]
= form_tag inbound_payments_path, method: :get do
  = select_month(Date.today, {use_two_digit_numbers: true, prefix: 'select'},{:field_name => 'month', :id => 'start-month'})
  = select_year(Date.today, {:start_year => DateTime.now.year,:end_year => 2030, prefix: 'select'},{:field_name => 'year', :id => 'start-year'})
  = submit_tag("Search", :id=>"button", :class=>"Test", :name=>"submit")
```

This way current_month is selected by default and I can select a month from dropdown. Everything works well. But how can I have the currently selected month and year automatically selected in the form, when params are passed and the form is submitted?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the solution!

controller:

```
  if params.has_key?(:select)
    @start_date = (params[:select][:year]+"-" + params[:select][:month]+"-"+Date.today.day.to_s).to_datetime.beginning_of_month
    @end_date = @start_date.end_of_month
    @inbound_payments = InboundPayment.where("created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?",@start_date, @end_date)
  else
    @inbound_payments = InboundPayment.where("created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?", Time.now.beginning_of_month, Time.now.end_of_month)
  end
```

view:

```
  - if params.has_key?(:select)
    = select_month(@start_date, {use_two_digit_numbers: true, prefix: 'select'},{:field_name => 'month', :id => 'start-month'})
    = select_year(@start_date, {:start_year => DateTime.now.year,:end_year => Tenant.current_tenant.created_at.year, prefix: 'select'},{:field_name => 'year', :id => 'start-year'})
  - else
    = select_month(Date.today, {use_two_digit_numbers: true, prefix: 'select'},{:field_name => 'month', :id => 'start-month'})
    = select_year(Date.today, {:start_year => DateTime.now.year,:end_year => Tenant.current_tenant.created_at.year, prefix: 'select'},{:field_name => 'year', :id => 'start-year'})
  = submit_tag("Search", :id=>"button", :class=>"Test", :name=>"submit")
```